# Latex error with fonts 1$\T1/futs/m/it/12

Tags: fonts

I have been getting this error in LaTeX:

```
! 1$\T1/futs/m/it/12 , $\FML/futmi/m/it/12 \T1/futs/m/n/12 (\FML/futmi/m/it/12
w[]\T1/futs/m/n/12 ) \FMS/futm/m/n/12 ! \T1/futs/m/n/12 0$ \T1/futs/m/it/12 an
```

I can't find anything on this error, neither on google nor in this site (sorry if there's a topic on this already). I have no idea what is about, I'm assuming it has to do with fonts.

Sorry for the unspecific question but I'm really stuck with this error. Does anybody have an idea on how to fix this or where I can find more information about this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a minimal code producing this error? It is related to the  `fourier` font, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: That is not an error message, it is hard to see the full context as you have not shown much of the log file but I suspect that it is a fragment of an over-full box message that just happens to have a `!` at the start of a line and your editor mis-parsed the log thinking it was an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions and ideas, I'm still unsure about the exact cause of the error. But the error appeared as soon as I added one particular equation to a particular line in the document.

It seems that the equation was too long to fit in the line, so I put it as a separate centered equation and the error disappeared. This produced the error:

> ... unless there is a sequence $\set{w_n}\subset W$ such that $w_n\rightarrow \infty$, $\mu(w_n)\rightarrow 0$ and $w_n \mu \parentesis{w_n} \rightarrow b \in \C^\ast$.

This solved it:

> ... unless there is a sequence $\set{w_n}\subset W$ such that $w_n\rightarrow \infty$, $\mu(w_n)\rightarrow 0$ and
>
> $$w_n \mu \parentesis{w_n} \rightarrow b \in \C^\ast.$$